# Can a Java Object be passed from Java Script to Applet

Tags: java, javascript, applet

Can you please let me know whether we can pass a Java Object from JavaScript to Applet .

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. Javascript can't make a java Object, since a java Object can only exist inside a JVM. Javascript doesn't run in a JVM. But javascript code can pass parameters (typically strings) to an applet, and you can call methods on your applet's top level class.

The best place to start is [Sun's documentation](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html). There's more description [here](http://www.codestore.net/store.nsf/unid/DOMM-4U8FM6), and an example [here](http://www.webdeveloper.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-20755.html).

Comment: Hi John Thanks for the reply , I request you for more Info . I mean can i pass any object (may be not of java ie may be from DB)  from Java Script to Java .

Comment: If your javascript can describe the object as strings, then yes. For example, if your object is a person with a firstname and a lastname, then you could call a java method setPerson(firstname,lastname).